# Удаление элементов из массива хешей

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

У меня есть массив

```
     @angars = [{"id"=>"j1_4", "text"=>"Москва", "data"=>{"display_name"=>"Москва", "availability_group_name"=>"true"}, "type"=>"file", "parent"=>"affil"},

{"id"=>"2", "text"=>"Архангельск",  "data"=>{"display_name"=>"Архангельск", "availability_group_name"=>"true"}, "type"=>"file", "parent"=>"affil"},

{"id"=>"3", "text"=>"Барнаул", "type"=>"file", "parent"=>"affil"},

{"id"=>"4", "text"=>"Белгород", "type"=>"file", "parent"=>"affil"},

{"id"=>"5", "text"=>"Владивосток", "type"=>"file", "parent"=>"affil"}, 

{"id"=>"6", "text"=>"Владимир",  "data"=>{"display_name"=>"Владимир", "availability_group_name"=>"false"}]
```

Суть задачи в том, чтобы отобразить выбранный город, остальные удалить.Делаю это так

```
      @angars = @angars.delete_if do |angar|
        if angar['data'].nil? || angar['data']['availability_group_name'] != 'true'
          angar['text'] != params[:city] #params[:city] - выбранный город
        end
      end
    end
```

При выборе городов с `availability_group_name == true` - все нормально,при выборе, где `data.nil?` выводит и этот город и все у которых `availability_group_name == true` . Признаться не могу понять в чем дело

Answer (score 0):

Потому что 
`angar['data'].nil? || angar['data']['availability_group_name'] != 'true’`
Вычисляется в `false` если у объекта `availability_group_name = true`, а значит не доходит до проверки `text` и блок возвращает nil => элемент не удаляется
Попробуйте так

```
 @angars = @angars.delete_if do |angar|
 unless angar.dig('data', 'availability_group_name') == true
    angar['text'] != params[:city] - выбранный город
  end
end
```